# How to find a value in excel sheet and then write another value in a different cell in the same row with openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am trying to search for a specific value in rows of an excel file.  Upon finding a matching value, I would like to write another value in the column next to the found value in the same row.

For instance, if I am looking for the word "test" and find it in cell A3, I would then want to print a specified value, say 6, in cell B3.

If it makes a difference, I do anticipate only having to search the A column for the value and always printing the other value to the B column in the same row.

Here is the code I have so far.

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet')
for row in ws.iter_rows():
    for cell in row:
        if cell.value == "test":
            ws.cell(row=cell, column=2).value = 6
wb.save(path)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is `gencal` and why does the code you have shown not do what you want?

Comment: Sorry, I tried to make my code generic from my real code and forgot to change that piece.

Comment: Great, that answers half of the question.  How about the other half?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line

```
 ws.cell(row=cell, column=2).value = 6
```

to

```
 ws.cell(row=cell.Row, column=2).value = 6
```

Comment: Or shorter - 

ws.cell(cell.Row, 2).Value = 6

Answer (score 0):

```
ws.cell(row=cell, column=2).value = 6
```

Should be

```
 ws.cell(row=cell, column=2, value=6)
```